# Socratic badge amount gone down unfairly with off-topic I cast on my own post

Tags: discussion, bug, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I feel that something rather unfair has just happened, so I would like to complain about it, my next gold badge that I will get is the Socratic, and just a few minutes ago it said:

[image]

Now however it has gone back to `97` from the `98` that it was on, and I am sure that I know the reason for this, for just a short while back I VTCed my [own question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673735/upon-switching-sound-output-device-sound-mutes) as off-topic because the problem had gone away, so the system detected this and decided that I had not maintained a positive question record today, but I don't think that this is fair for I was the one who cast the first close vote on my own question for going away by itself, now I don't see how that means that my question record for today has suddenly gone bad!

I assume that that is the reason for why it went down for my badge anyway, of course I can't be absolutely certain of it, but my other questions look absolutely fine, so I assume that that is the reason for my 'bad' question record today.
But I don't think it is fair, and I think that something needs to change in regard to this...

Comment: Don't complain, with your current question rate you will still get the badge within this week.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I'm still unhappy with it...

Comment: Why didn't you just delete it?

Comment: @Oli: Because in the future I may want to reopen it, and I won't be able to find it after a while if I just delete it...

Comment: Ah that's the reason - I was already wondering about your (not all the time useful)  questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off-topic is considered a negative close reason, whoever started it.

In the future, if you post something that you're not sure about, just delete it. You should be able to undelete it later on if you need to. You might be able to see [your recently deleted](https://askubuntu.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/364819) through your profile.